# Timeouts to certain endpoints via digitalocean reserved ip

Tags: networking, centos-8, digital-ocean

When following the instrctions on https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/networking/reserved-ips/how-to/outbound-traffic/ some endpoints work fine while others just time out.

`ping` and `mtr` reach the endpoints without givig informatin about any intermidiate hop, e.g.

```
> mtr -rwbzc100  redis-xyz.b.db.ondigitalocean.com
Start: 2024-03-14T10:39:20+0200
HOST: x.y          Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
1. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
2. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
3. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
4. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
5. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
6. AS???    ???                           100.0   100    0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
7. AS14061  207.154.212.65                 0.0%   100    0.9   0.8   0.5   3.1   0.3
```

Example working endpoint: maskyoo.co.il
Example timeout endpoint: smtp.mailgun.com

I tried stopping NetworkManager to no avail.
regarding outputs of `route -n` or `ip r`, I went through various configurations but notably whenever outgoing traffic is routed via my reserved IP (as attested by `wget -qO- icanhazip.com`) I get timeouts and whenever it's routed via the regular public IP everything is peachy.

As far as I can tell this issue started since migrating from CentOS 7 to CentOS 8 Stream, but I don't know how to rightly troubleshoot it and point at the culprit.